# Why doesn't Search "all mailboxes" show results from all mailboxes?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I have two mailboxes (personal and a customer support mailbox everyone has access to) in Outlook 365 Windows client.

If I enable "All Mailboxes" or "All Outlook Items" in the search tab my searches only apply to my primary personal account:

- Search `Tools -> Locations to Search` only shows my personal email account.
- The only way I can find to search the other mailbox is to access `Search -> Search Tools -> Advanced Find`, press `Browse`
- When I try to select the customer service inbox, it tells me I have to deselect everything else first

[image]

So I cannot search both mailboxes at the same time - and it's very convoluted to do a search. Is there some setting that's wrong or does this suggest the way the mailbox is set up on the server is causing problems... or something else?

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I noticed that you have configured a personal account and an account which is "a customer support mailbox everyone has access to", is it a shared mailbox?

Based on my test, I have done several tests in my Outlook 365 (version is as shown in the below figure) with two personal accounts configured and i could search emails from all mailboxes successfully, which didn't reproduce you issue. It's suggested that you could try to configure two personal accounts to test if there're any differences.

[image]

If it's a shared mailbox, as I know, **to search a Shared Mailbox, we need to click the mailbox and use the Current Folder scope.** This is by design. To work around this issue, you can add the Shared Mailbox as a secondary Exchange account to the profile.

[image]

For more information, please refer to: [No results are returned if you use the All Mailboxes scope](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshooting-outlook-search-issues-2556b11f-f4d8-46be-b0a7-de33a3f4f066#:%7E:text=No%20results%20are%20returned%20if%20you%20use%20the%20All%20Mailboxes%20scope).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.